# Alert user without refreshing the page in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php code that alerts when a user delete a record, but it refreshes the page upon alerting, then the background page become blank, which seems quite annoying. How will I do it without refreshing the page? Below is my sample code named deleteuser.php.

```
<?
include 'mysqlcon.php'; // my connection credentials to php

$postudel = $_POST['enterudel'];

if($postudel!="")
    {
    $sqldel = "DELETE FROM User WHERE UserName = '$postudel'";
    $getdel = mysql_query($sqldel,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('User $postudel successfully deleted.');";
    echo "</script>";
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Delete User</title>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function deluser()
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
if (r==true)
    {
    var objsel = document.getElementById("duser");
    var udel = objsel.options[objsel.selectedIndex].id;
    document.formdel.enterudel.value = udel;
    document.formdel.submit();
    }
    else
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="50%" align="left">
<tr><td width="50%" colspan="2">
<big>Delete User:</big>
</td></tr>

<tr><td width="25%">
Username:&nbsp;
<SELECT id="duser">
<option>Choose One</option>
<?
$sqldu=mysql_query("SELECT UserName from User");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqldu))
{
    echo "<OPTION ID=".$row['UserName'];
    echo ">".$row['UserName']."</OPTION>";
}
?>
</SELECT>
</td>

<td width="25%">
<input type="button" value="Delete" id="delete" onClick="deluser()">
</td></tr>
</table>

<form name="formdel" action="../deleteuser.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="enterudel" value="<?=$postudel?>">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try use jquery ajax at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split

```
if($postudel!="")
    {
    $sqldel = "DELETE FROM User WHERE UserName = '$postudel'";
    $getdel = mysql_query($sqldel,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('User $postudel successfully deleted.');";
    echo "</script>";
    }
```

up in two parts :

```
if($postudel!="")
    {
    $sqldel = "DELETE FROM User WHERE UserName = '$postudel'";
    $getdel = mysql_query($sqldel,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

where it is now, and

```
<?
if($postudel!="")
    {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('User $postudel successfully deleted.');";
    echo "</script>";
    }
?>
```

before `</body>`. Then you will delete and draw the page before the alert, avoiding blank page